# How to force R plots y axis to start at y=0 and keep the color?

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

I am now trying to plot the Probability Density Functuion of some data, and I find the is some distance between `y=0`and x axis. I tried to set `yaxs="i"`, but then the x axis will become grey. Is there any solution? Thanks. Here is an example

```
set.seed(100)
plot(density(rnorm(100)),xlab="",ylab="",main="")
```

[image]

```
plot(density(rnorm(100)),yaxs="i",xlab="",ylab="",main="")
```

As you can see, the color of the x axis will become grey. How to make it black?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the gray line is that you are calling `plot.density` when you pass an object class `density` to `plot`.  `plot.density` has a `zero.line` argument which is set to TRUE and plots the gray line using `abline(h = 0, lwd = 0.1, col = "gray")` by default (see `stat:::plot.density` for code).  You need to set `zero.line` to FALSE.

```
plot(density(nums), yaxs="i", 
    xlab="", ylab="", main="",
    zero.line = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can control the upper `ylim` too if you want to give some more room at the top than `yaxs = "i"` would give otherwise.  Of course, you still need `zero.line = FALSE` to not plot the gray zero line.

```
plot(density(nums), yaxs="i",
    xlab="", ylab="", main="",
    zero.line = FALSE,
    ylim = c(0, 0.5)) # put whatever you want here instead 0.5
```

---

An alternative solution would be to cover the gray line with another line:

```
plot(density(nums), yaxs="i",
    xlab="", ylab="", main="")
abline(h = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are awesome. `zero.line = FALSE` does work, but setting `ylim` will not work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the ylim, it should work.

```
d <- density(rnorm(100))
plot(d, xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim = c(0,max(d$y)), yaxs = "i")
```

you could also specify

```
par(col.axis = "black")
```

Looks as follows, i.e., starting at 0 and keeping the color.

```
d <- density(rnorm(100))
plot(d, xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim = c(0,max(d$y)+.05), yaxs = "i",
     col.axis = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce your error actually. `plot(density(rnorm(100)),yaxs="i",xlab="",ylab="",main="")` gives me a normal black axis.

Comment: Hi, I have just copied your code and run, but the x axis is still grey. I am using R version 3.3.1. Thanks.

Comment: This might be trivial but did you try `par(col.axis= "black")`? It could be a global parameter that you have previously set?

Comment: I have not set any global parameter about axis color and I have not tried `par(col.axis= "black")` as  well. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but neither of your solutions work for me.  I'm not sure why you don't get the gray line, which is shown by default with `stats:::plot.density`